# Gradle - exclude jar from dependencies only for production

Tags: grails, gradle, build.gradle, grails-3.1

I'm about to deploy my Grails 3 web-app using `gradle assemble` to create the war file, and I'm trying to exclude a few jar files from it.

In particular I added in my `build.gradle` configuration file

```
dependencies {
    [...]
    assets 'com.bertramlabs.plugins:sass-asset-pipeline:2.7.2'
}
```

These are the internal dependencies for the above plugin, which helps me to process SASS files into CSS

```
 \--- com.bertramlabs.plugins:sass-asset-pipeline:2.7.2
      +--- com.bertramlabs.plugins:asset-pipeline-core:2.7.2
      |    +--- org.mozilla:rhino:1.7R4
      |    +--- com.google.javascript:closure-compiler:v20151015
      |    \--- commons-logging:commons-logging:1.1.1
      +--- log4j:log4j:1.2.17
      +--- org.jruby:jruby-complete:1.7.11 -> 1.7.18
      \--- com.bertramlabs.plugins:jruby-container:0.6.1
           \--- org.jruby:jruby-complete:1.7.18
```

I excluded the `org.ruby` group as the jar is 22MB and is not needed in production as the `assemble` task already bundles my css resources.

```
configurations {
    compile.exclude group: 'org.jruby'
    [...]
}
```

This works for production environment but the dependency is instead needed for development.

Is there a quick way to achieve this? Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks to Arjang suggestion this solved my problem (though I'm sure there must me some other solution)

```
assets ("com.bertramlabs.plugins:sass-asset-pipeline:2.7.2") {
    if(project.gradle.startParameter.taskNames.contains('assemble')) {
        exclude group: 'org.jruby'
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

i have not tested this yet. In build.gradle in dependencies put

```
if (!project.hasProperty('grailsEnv') || project.grailsEnv.equals('dev')) { compile.exclude group: 'org.jruby' }
```

Comment: I didn't know something like `project` was included in the scope, this helped me a lot!
Unfortunately there's no `grailsEnv` property, but after a few attempts I came up with a solution (answer added).

Comment: Thanks for the solution. I saw my solution in [here](http://www.grailsbrasil.com.br/post/show/2972).